# Movie where kids push dead cow?

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a horror movie where a couple of kids go on a farm at night to push a cow so that it falls on the ground, but when it falls, they see that it was already dead.

It's the only thing I can remember from the movie. Does anyone know which one I'm talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the 2005 made-for-TV film "[Larva](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0393421/)".

The cow-tipping scene is described [here](http://celluloidcemetery.blogspot.co.uk/2005/11/larva-2005-tv.html);

> The movie starts off in a Missouri field with four teenagers going cow
>   tipping. The cow in question is already dead on its feet, obviously
>   the victim of the title beasties. (Ah, the irony!) However, the scene
>   ends flat with the teens running off prior to the larva sluggishly (no
>   pun intended) breaking through the animal's hide as the credits begin.

The cow-tipping scene can be seen right at the start of the movie. Unfortunately the clip is in Hindi, but you get the idea.

Comment: yes that's it, thank you so much!!

Comment: @Thomas - Don't forget to upvote as well :-)